# Multiple htaccess files not working as aspected

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

So I am having a weird problem with `htaccess` and that is multiple `htaccess` files not working.

Lets go in detail

**Note** - Using **CPanel** for updating my server not any sever agent like **filezilla**

This year on **Jan** I have uploaded my site and it works fine with multiple `htaccess` files in it. let me show you the folder structure.

```
public_html  ( inside )

    project1  --- include one .htaccess file
       d1  -  index.html and other html, css, js files  --- include one .htaccess file
       d2  -  index.html and other html, css, js files  --- include one .htaccess file
       d3  -  index.html and other html, css, js files  --- include one .htaccess file
```

1. **project 1** folder contain one htaccess file which have `indexignore *` written inside it.
2. **d1**, **d2**, **d3** folder these folder contains one `htaccess` files in each of them.

The links are given below

```
https//example.com/project1

https//example.com/project1/d1

https//example.com/project1/d2

https//example.com/project1/d3
```

till this time it works fine.

Now I am updating server with new project so now the file structure are as follows

```
public_html  ( inside )

    project1  --- include one .htaccess file
       d1  -  index.html and other html, css, js files  --- include one .htaccess file
       d2  -  index.html and other html, css, js files  --- include one .htaccess file
       d3  -  index.html and other html, css, js files  --- include one .htaccess file


    project2
       d1  -  index.html and other html, css, js files  --- include one .htaccess file 
       d2  -  index.html and other html, css, js files   --- include one .htaccess file
       d3  -  index.html and other html, css, js files  --- include one .htaccess file
```

1. **Project 1** - same as before but change is made in htaccess file inside the project 1 folder that include `indexignore *` code in it the htaccess file is update by the [leverage browser cache code.](https://www.wpfaster.org/code/how-to-leverage-browser-caching-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin)

**About project 2**

1. **project 2** folder contain one htaccess file which have `indexignore *` written inside it.
2. **d1**, **d2**, **d3** folder ( inside project 2 ) these folder contains one `htaccess` files in each of them.

   The links are given below

   ```
   https//example.com/project2

   https//example.com/project2/d1

   https//example.com/project2/d2

   https//example.com/project2/d3
   ```

**Note**- Yes, the information of structure and htaccess file is same as **project 1** as mentined above *( Project 2 - contains the same as project one includeing its sub folder same htaccess files )*

So now htaccess files work in project 1 but not in project 2.

**Update**

**What I need**

The indexignore * and leverage browser cache code works fine in project 1 but it does not work in project 2 as I have checked many time in [gtmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/) and [pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com/) it gives me leverage browser cache error in project 2.

Comment: what the htaccess files content? what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @shushu304 update my question